# random 'module' object has no attribute 'randit'; random.__file__ directs to right module in library frameworks; other solutions have not worked

Tags: python, module

i've looked at other threads looking at the same problems and the solutions suggested there have not worked

whenever i try to execute this code i get this

```
import random
print random.randit(0,5)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randit'
```

to see if there was a file that was named random before it reaches the correct random.py i did

```
random.__file__
```

which gave me this readout

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/random.pyc'
```

I went to that folder and checked out random.py and confirmed that it has the function randit;

i've tried moving my code so that my working directory is in the python2.5/random.pyc directory and it still does not work. 
i've tried moving the random.py from framework library into my working directory of my code and it is not working; i checked the random.**file** after doing so and it does not switch to  the current working directory that contains a copy of the random.py from frameworks

furthermore, i have tried reinstalling python as well which did not change anything

this code was working before, but when I tried to run that line in a bigger set of code that wasn't exporting any files and is not named random, thats when I stopped being able to run the random.randit function even in a completely new .py file in a completely new working directory

lastly, i've tried importing the math module and that module works fine

does anyone have any suggestions for what else I can do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think your code had a typo it's `randint` not `randit`.

```
import random
print random.randint(0,5)
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped then up vote it and tick the right answer beside my answer to let others know it worked. :P